# Visual Studio: Tables always added offscreen when editing EDMX files

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, asp.net

I have a number of ASP.NET projects which utilise `.edmx` files to access tables on the relevant database for each app. If I add a new table, I have to open the `.edmx` and click `Update Model from Database`. This always seems to add any new tables very far down the page and often to the right. I always then have to zoom out to find them, or go scrolling around.

Why does Visual Studio add these off screen? Is there any way to change it?